# Unable to access Gerrit changes details from python-gerrit-api

Tags: python, git, api, gerrit, rest

I am trying to access particular gerrit details based on it's change-id. But unable to get the details.

I have used [python-gerrit-api](https://pypi.org/project/python-gerrit-api/). code snippet as follows

**from gerrit import GerritClient**

**gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="base-url-gerrit", username='xxxxx', password='xxxxxx', ssl_verify=False, cert=None)**

**change = gerrit.changes.get('123456')**

but response getting as "**404 Client Error: Not Found for url**"

when I try to access same url "https://base-gerrit.com/changes/123456", directly json data is downloading.

Please let me know where did I do wrong, is there any otherway to get the change details based on change-id.

Comment: Make sure that you use the http password instead of the login password. The http password can be generated in the user settings.

Comment: I have created http password. Still facing same issue. Do I need to use http:base-gerrit.com instead of https:base-gerrit.com ?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pygerrit2/ package is working fine.